# Which is better between Synchronous and Asynchronous Requests in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit

I used both of that methods and it still OK but when use Synchronous method we have to create new thread to avoid `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. So which is better between it. With Synchronous method we can return directly values of response and use it many time with `call.execute().body`

Comment: There is not a right answer. It depends on your needs. Usually in order to left the UI-thread free, you shuold call a WS asynchronously, however if your call is already in a Thread (for some reason) probably you can use a Synchronous call.

Comment: if we create new thread to handle synchronous method. do it affect to our other thread or main thread?

Comment: If your call is synchronous called from a worker thread, only the worker thread will be busy, until the call returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already on a background thread (e.g., `IntentService`), and you need to use Retrofit, use the synchronous approach.

If you are on the main application thread, and you need to use Retrofit, and you have no other need to manage your own background thread for this work, use the asynchronous approach.